# How to edit a selected SubItem programmatically?

Tags: c#, listview, selecteditem, subitem

Does anyone know how can I edit a subitem on a listView? I've tried using this:

```
ListView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[1].Text = "Hello?";
```

But that doesn't work. I get the error "InvalidArgument=Value of '1' is not valid for 'index'". I've got two columns on the listview, so I figured the index of [1] would be the subitem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you actually added an item with a subitem to the list? Just because you have two columns the ListViewItem doesn't automatically get 2 subitems.

For example if you have done the following:

```
ListViewItem item = listView1.Items.Add("test");  
item.SubItems.Add("sub1");
```

Then it should work, but if you only have:

```
ListViewItem item = listView1.Items.Add("test");
```

Then it won't.

Comment: Ahh, thanks. It works now. I just assumed that it already had a value that could be edited. Thanks again.